# VFX: compositing a 3D scene with a green screen video

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, video

can someone explain to me how to composite a scene (setting) in 3D with a green screen video? I've already done the tracking and the mask but from there on I don't know how to go about it and I can't find a tutorial that does it all in Blender!

Answer (score 0):

*Green Screen* is mostly a compositor/vse workflow. Ryan King did a good tutorial on that topic:
[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBBkgoDPnZE